# MacOS - What is wrong with my launchd plist?

Tags: macos, plist, sudo, launchd, launch-daemon

MacOS High Sierra, I have a plist I want to use with launchd.

I am trying to use this in `~/Library/LaunchDaemon` but it is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.myscript.mac.plist</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/private/var/myscript.sh</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>        
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

When I use `sudo lauchctl load com.myscript.mac.plist` nothing is output.
No confirmation message, no error message, nothing. This is where I seem to have stalled.

The top-level folder `private` is hidden, in case that makes any difference.

What is wrong with my script? Why can I not get it to run?

Answer (score 0):

Three possible reasons:

1. The `Label` in the plist must be specified without the extension: `com.myscript.mac`
2. If the daemon is located in the user library it must be loaded without `sudo`
3. The folder name is `LaunchDaemons` (with trailing `s`)

Comment: 1. I have seen examples using both with and without however I will try your suggestion. 2. Can you explain this particular point further: "located in the user library"? By using it as a LaunchDaemons doesn't it run for all and any users as root user anyway? Regarding not loading with sudo, is this important? I thought that once it had been loaded that it would always run from that point onwards?

Comment: There are two different locations `~/Library/LaunchDaemons` (where `~` represents the User's home folder) and `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, the local (main) domain. The former has to be loaded without `sudo` the latter with `sudo`